# SIMPLE Column formatting in SharePoint list (SP2019)

Tags: list, modern-experience, json-formatting, 2019, column-formatting

I have a pretty basic SharePoint list on a page at work and I simply want columns to be colored yellow (Is it "#ffff00" ?).

In my "List Settings" I select the column I would like to format.
On the Settings > Edit Column page, I scroll all the way to the bottom where the box to apply JSON code is.

All I want to do is make the background color of the column yellow.
No "if = " functionality required.

I've referenced several other posts, but could not find a **simple** formatting solution.

Any help would be super appreciated!

TIA!

Answer (score 0):

Try using this SharePoint column formatting JSON:

```
{
   "$schema": "https://developer.microsoft.com/json-schemas/sp/v1/column-formatting.schema.json",
   "elmType": "div",
   "txtContent": "@currentField"
   "style": {
       "color": "yellow"
   }
}
```

**Microsoft Documentation**: [Use column formatting to customize SharePoint](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting)

Comment: Make sure to use v1 schema for SP 2019 as given above. Also txtContent value might change based on column type. @currentField should work for simple column types like text, number, date, single selection choice, etc.

Comment: Thank you for your response!
Unfortunately this doesn't work either... :(

Comment: Are you using modern experience list view? JSON formatting does not work in classic experience. Also, follow the steps given here for apply column formatting: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/declarative-customization/column-formatting